# How to write the XML path in snowflake code. I have the sq server code, I need to convert to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can you please help me in converting the sql server code to snowflake code,

I am not sure how to write the XMl step in snowflake

**Code:**

```
SELECT  Name, Number,    
Code = SUBSTRING(select '_ ' + F.Code       
from AA AS A    
JOIN BB AS B  on B.Consumer = A.Consumer   
JOIN CC AS C on C.Contact = B.Contact       
JOIN FF AS F on E.Code = F.Code      
and F.Code IN ('DX','DP','DS')    
For XML path(''),elements),2,500)

FROM 
from AA AS a WITH (NOLOCK)      
JOIN BB b WITH (NOLOCK) on b.Consumer = a.Consumer     
JOIN CC AS c on C.Contact = B.Contact     
JOIN DD AS d on C.Unit = D.Unit
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store XML data as a variant type in Snowflake. Snowflake does not currently support xpath expressions, so you can use the XMLGET function. If you need to get n-levels deep in the XML, you can nest the function such as:

```
 select xmlget(xmlget(xmlget(XML_FILE, 'Student', 1), 'course'), 'gym'):"$"::string as GRADE from XML_TEST;
```

I wrote a quick-start guide for a few of my customers from sources annotated in the SQL worksheet. It tries to cover the key concepts quickly rather than in detail. If you need more detail, I recommend the links in the SQL comments.

```
--https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Querying-Nested-XML-in-Snowflake
--https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Lateral-Join-Tutorial
--https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/introduction-to-loading-and-parsing-xml-data-using-sql

-- Set the context
use warehouse test;
use database test;
use schema public;

-- For convenience, we'll create a simple function to return a hard-coded XML document.
-- Note that the document is three layers deep from the root, 
-- for example SchoolRoster/Student/Course/Math
create or replace function GetSampleXML ()
  returns string
  language javascript
  as
  $$
    var s = 
`<SchoolRoster>
   <Student>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>14</age>
      <course>
         <math>A</math>
         <english>B</english>
      </course>
      <course>
         <government>A+</government>
      </course>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <name>Tom</name>
      <age>13</age>
      <course>
         <gym>A</gym>
         <geography>incomplete</geography>
      </course>
   </Student>
</SchoolRoster>`;

    return s;

  $$
  ;

-- Confirm that we can select the user-defined function, and it returns the XML document.
select GetSampleXML() as XML_FILE;

-- Create a simple table that has just a single variant column to hold the XML.
create or replace table XML_TEST (XML_FILE variant);

-- Insert the sample XML document as a variant into the fist row.
insert into XML_TEST (XML_FILE) select PARSE_XML(GetSampleXML());

-- Confirm that the table looks right, one row containing the XML document
select * from XML_TEST;

-- Get the un-flattened student information for the first student (0 based).
select xmlget(XML_FILE, 'Student', 0):"$" from XML_TEST;

-- Break up the XML file into the top-level nodes, one row for "John" and one for "Tom"
select FLAT.VALUE
from XML_TEST X, 
     LATERAL FLATTEN( INPUT => XML_FILE:"$" ) FLAT;

-- Get a value three layers deep on the SECOND student (0 based)
select xmlget(xmlget(xmlget(XML_FILE, 'Student', 1), 'course'), 'gym'):"$"::string as GRADE from XML_TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular case can be handled using simple LISTAGG function in Snowflake as the XML path tag is defined as ('') i.e. empty without tag specifications.

```
SELECT  Name, Number,    
 SUBSTRING((select LISTAGG('_ ' || F.Code , '')       
from AA AS A    
JOIN BB AS B  on B.Consumer = A.Consumer   
JOIN CC AS C on C.Contact = B.Contact       
JOIN FF AS F on E.Code = F.Code      
and F.Code IN ('DX','DP','DS')    
For XML path(''),elements),2,500) AS Code

FROM 
from AA AS a WITH (NOLOCK)      
JOIN BB b WITH (NOLOCK) on b.Consumer = a.Consumer     
JOIN CC AS c on C.Contact = B.Contact     
JOIN DD AS d on C.Unit = D.Unit
```

Note that, when the XML path is '', the behavior is same as concat/transpose of the column values as one single value.
However, in case if there was a path defined, then this would not work.